# Integration regarding joint probability density functions to find required probabilities

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, density-function

**Edit**

It seems I could not evaluate $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4)$ correctly as I had wrongly assumed that $4 - x$ is always positive, when in actual fact it could be negative, so there was another case to consider, which I had missed. Many thanks to users @MathLover and @StubbornAtom for their answers!

---

**Question**

Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint probability density function (PDF) $$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = e^{-x},\quad 0 < y < x.$$

Find $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4\ |\ Y = 2)$.

---

**My working**

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4) & = \mathbb{P}(Y > 4 - X)
\\[5 mm] & =
\int^{\infty}_0 \int^x_{4 - x} e^{-x}\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x
\\[5 mm] & =
-2
\end{align}

---

The answer clearly cannot be $-2$, since we are dealing with probability and my best guess is my limits of integration are incorrect. In particular, I think the support for the given joint PDF is throwing me off - I am not sure how to interpret it.

I also have no clue how to proceed with $\mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4\ |\ Y = 2)$, so any hints for this part will be nice as well :)

Comment: Draw your region of integration. It should become obvious that you will need two integrals to compute the probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed that $0 \lt y \lt x$. At intersection of $y = 4-x$ and $y = x, x = 2$. Also at intersection of $y = 0$ and $y = 4 - x, x = 4$

[image]

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(X + Y > 4) = \int_2^4 \int^x_{4 - x} e^{-x}\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x + \int_4^{\infty} \int_0^x e^{-x}\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am still trying to understand why the required probability is the shaded area. In particular, where did the line $y = x$ come from? I mean, what is the intuition here?

Comment: That is coming from density function $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = e^{-x},\quad 0 < y < x$

Comment: Okay. I think I am getting it. I have one more question. I notice that all of the bounds of integration are in terms of $x$ values. Would it be possible to find the probability by changing all of the bounds of integration to the corresponding $y$ values?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Between $0 \leq y \leq 2$, $4-y \leq x \leq \infty$ and between $2 \leq y \leq \infty$, $y \leq x \leq \infty$

Comment: Do you know how to go about the second question?

Comment: I see! I have accepted your answer as I find it more intuitive than the other answer, which evaluated the integral algebraically. I still have trouble understanding that. And yes, I think I know how to approach the second question :)

Comment: Ok great. If you have any further questions, I can explain in chat.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds of integration are incorrect, since you have to incorporate the fact that support of $(X,Y)$ is the set $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:0<y<x\}$. This means joint density of $(X,Y)$ is actually $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-x} \mathbf1_{0<y<x}$ where $\mathbf1$ is an indicator function. In other words, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-x}$ if $(x,y)\in S$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)\notin S$.

Therefore,

\begin{align}
P(Y>4-X)&=\int_0^\infty\left\{\int_{\max(0,4-x)}^x e^{-x}\,\mathrm dy\right\}\mathbf1_{x>4-x}\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\int_2^4 e^{-x}\int_{4-x}^x \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx+\int_4^\infty e^{-x} \int_0^x \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\cdots
\end{align}

The other probability is $P(X>2\mid Y=2)$, for which you require the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$. Now the joint density factors as

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-(x-y)}\mathbf1_{x>y} \cdot e^{-y}\mathbf1_{y>0}$$

This suggests that the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ is

$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=e^{-(x-y)}\mathbf1_{x>y}$$

Hence, $$P(X>2\mid Y=2)=\int_2^\infty f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 2)\,\mathrm dx=\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am having difficulty understanding how you "expanded" the inner integral, as I have never come across an integral with max/min in the bounds of integration before. Do you mind explaining that part a little further? Is there a theorem for that or something?

Comment: $y>\max(a,b)$ is just a compact way of writing $y>a$ and $y>b$ simultaneously. If you are not comfortable with this, then best to draw a picture as already suggested.

Comment: Yes... I have difficulty seeing how you split up the integral afterwards. Indeed, I find the graphical method easier. However, your answer has still helped me because you gave some guidance on the second question, so I gave you an upvote too :)

Comment: Splitting up the integral is the easier part. You consider cases when $y>4-x$ and when $y>0$. The first one is true if $4-x>0$, i.e. if $x<4$ and similarly the second one is true if $x>4$. Plus you have to keep in mind throughout that $x>4-x$, i.e. $x>2$.

Comment: Huh... Now that you put it that way, this method is just as easy too. I just have trouble seeing how we know that $x > 4 - x$. Is it because, from the support, we know that $x > y$ and, from the required probability, we know that $y > 4 - x$, so putting both together, we have $x > 4 - x$?

Comment: That's right...